# How to set Constraints in Xcode Using StoryBoard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to set constraints in iphone devices using storyboard in xcode. But i am getting some issue.I have placed two textfields and two buttons using drag and drop.Everything is going fine except one button whose width get reduced in iphone 5s and i don't know the reason behind this.Can anybody help?

[png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boKBU.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! SO specifically focuses on programming related questions. And hence this question might not be suitable here. But you can use a different forum https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Its because iPhone 5s screen is smaller than iPhone 6, 6s and other iPhones. There are lots of tutorial on youtube and google just go learn them. After that when you face problem in set auto layout ask here again

Answer (score 0):

Vandana, if the button width is reduced, it simply means that it does not have a fix width. You have 2 options

1) Set a width constraint on the button (e.g. I want it to be 300 points long)

2) Set a leading and trailing constraint (e.g. on the left I want a fix 10 points distance from the bezel, and on the right I want a fix 10 points distance from the bezel.

I believe there's a warning in the storyboard, you just need to select the best option for you:

[image]

Ways to add a width constraint:

1) Option + click and hold "the button"
2) drag to the left or right on storyboard and release while it's on the button:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some practical solutions:

- add a "width" constraint for that button ( it can be >= also )
- adde "equal widths" constraint for that button and another element
- adde "trailing and leading" constraint for that button

also

- try with different size classes to see your result.

It would also help your question to add more info on how your constraints are setup.

Comment: what are size classes and why they are used?